# Cannot get Microsoft Surface to boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

Okay, I have previously been able to boot from a USB drive without issue. Then 2 days ago something changed and I can only boot to Grub off of USB. I have essentially tried everything. I have tried Rufus, Unetbootin, and Ventoy. Have gone thru Secure Boot being off, on and even the Microsoft and third party option. Have even tired to (from Grub) list the disks and cannot find any file that involves or says boot on drive. Whats really annoying is booting off a second laptop with Ubuntu already installed makes drive work after showing the missing /boot partition. How can the not boot be possible when trying several different downloads of Ubuntu, several different ISO writers, messing with secure boot. Nothing works!!!